# Got an attribute error when predicting a prebuild tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.autograph.operators' has no attribute 'UndefinedReturnValue

I was trying to predict images with a prebuild CNN neural model json file and model weights with cifar10 network but got the above got the above error

Comment: Please check and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)